# Java generics with List

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

I want to clarify something. This is my code:

```
List<GameObject>[] dynamicCells;                      //1
List<GameObject>[] staticCells;                       //2

dynamicCells = new List[numCells];                    //3
staticCells = new List[numCells];                     //4

for (int i = 0; i < numCells; i++) {
    dynamicCells[i] = new ArrayList<GameObject>(10);  //5
    staticCells[i] = new ArrayList<GameObject>(10);   //6
}
```

On the first and second step I create an "empty" array of `GameObject` list reference.
On the third and fourth step I allocate memory for an array of List which I return its address reference. On the 5, 6 step I create a new `ArrayList` reference of type `GameObject` which I assign on my List.

So in the end I am left with an array Of list references that each one hold an `ArrayList` of game objects. Is this right ? Is there any better way to explain this ?

Comment: That's correct. Each variable is an array of `List` objects.

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2 are **variable declarations**, nothing is created there.

3 and 4 create arrays and assign them to the variables (in the process allocating memory, but only for the arrays of object references).

5 and 6 create new empty generic ArrayLists that are assigned to a position in the array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as i said i was pretty confused but now i am sure :)